# how to import React component from submodule?

Tags: reactjs, git-submodules

I have a parent repository developed with React, and I have a child Sub Module inside of it(which is developed in react too``

The project folder structure is like below`

```
main-project
  /.git
  /node_modules
  /src
  /babel.config.json
  /CKLibs/ck_commun
     /.git
     /node_modules
     /src
       /js
         /About.jsx //  i want to import this file of submodule in parent project
     /...
  /...
```

I want to access and use the About.jsx component from submodule into parent project.

```
import About from 'ck_commun/src/js/About'
```

the dependency ck_commun is declared like this in package.json

```
 "ck_commun": "file:./CKLibs/ck_commun",
```

i am having this error

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./CKLibs/ck_commun/src/assets/shared/pages/About.jsx 5:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import React from 'react'
| const About = () => {
>     return (<>hello</>)
| };
```

it's like it can't transpile jsx code in js code, i added babel.config.json under the root of main-project

```
 {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread"
    ],
    "babelrcRoots": [ "./", "./CKLibs/ck_commun" ]
  }
```

but anything changed,
my package.json of the submodule contains

```
{
  "name": "ck_commun",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have the very same problem as well. Did you manage to find a solution?